# Find the angles between the following pairs of vectors

Tags: vectors

$a = (i + j)$

$b = (2i-3j)$

$$a \cdot b = (i + j) \cdot (2i - 3j)$$
$$=2(1) - 3(1) \Rightarrow 2-3 = -1$$

$$\|a\|=\sqrt{2}$$

$$\|b\|=i\sqrt{5}$$

$$\cos \theta=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}\implies\theta=\arccos \left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}\right)$$

$$\theta=108.4^\circ$$

My answer is wrong, it is supposed to be $101.3^\circ$

Comment: How did you compute the norm of $a$?

Comment: You have $||a||=\sqrt{2}$ and $||b||=\sqrt{13}$

Comment: @PeterMelech how did you get, $||b|| = \sqrt(13)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow{a}= \hat{i}+\hat{j},\space and \space \overrightarrow{b}=2\hat{i}-3\hat{j},\space \parallel\overrightarrow{a} \parallel=\sqrt{2},\space \parallel\overrightarrow{b} \parallel=\sqrt{2^2+(-3)^2}=\sqrt{13}$$
$$\Rightarrow \overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{b}=2-3\Rightarrow \cos{\theta}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{26}} \Rightarrow \theta=\arccos{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{26}}} \approx 101.3 ^\circ$$

> You evaluated  the magnitude of **b** mistakenly

Comment: How do you get to $\sqrt(26)$?